# Error: undefined property $load

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter, and I have developed a code to carry out queries on the database. I load the database using`$this->load->database();` and perform a query, but when I run the code, the browser gives me the following error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Tutorial::$load.
Fatal error: Call to a member function database() on a non-object
```

This is the code I am using:

```
class Tutorial extends CI_Controller {
    public function tutorial() {
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT user,pass,email FROM tablex');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            echo $row->title;
            echo $row->name;
        }
```

I am sure the `$db` variables in my database configuration file are properly set and I have even tried autoloading the database for all pages in the autoload.php config file; still having the same problem. Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: use a model, it will work there.

Comment: Where is `load` defined?

Comment: used a model, gave me almost the same error message, except this time the fatal error reads `Call to a member function model() on a non-object`. So I can neither load the database() nor model(). Should it be a problem with load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeIgniter User Guide, [Creating Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) Section:

> To access CodeIgniter's native resources within your library use the
>   **get_instance()** function. This function returns the CodeIgniter super
>   object.
>   Normally from within your controller functions you will call any of
>   the available CodeIgniter functions using the **$this** construct.
>
> **$this**, however, only works directly within your controllers, your
>   models, or your views. If you would like to use CodeIgniter's classes
>   from within your own custom classes you can do so as follows:
>
> First, assign the CodeIgniter object to a variable:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

> Once you've assigned the object to a variable, you'll use that
>   variable instead of **$this**:

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
etc.
```

Hope this helps. You could also put the $CI in a constructor.

Your code would look something like this:

```
class Tutorial
{
    public $CI;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!isset($this->CI))
        {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
        }
        $this->CI->load->database();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
$this->load->database();
```

to

```
$this->load->library('database');
```

database is not a direct method. It is a library in codeigniter and you have to load it as a library.

You can also autoload `database` library in `autoload.php`.

**UPDATE:**

You are using the same name for your class and method. In PHP4, a method which has the same name as class name was treated as constructor, but if you are using codeigniter 2+, you have to use PHP5 constructor which is

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    /*Additional code which you want to run automatically in every function call */
}
```

You cannot give a method same name as class name in Codeigniter 2+. Change the method to anything else. You can name the method `index` if you want it to load by default.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: `$this->load->library('database')` still gives me the same error message, except this time the error message replaces `database()` with `library()`. I am thinking the problem should be with `load` because I used a model and the error message still appeared, this time pointing to `model()`, that is: `Fatal error: call to a member function model() on a non-object.` Still cant fix it. It's been hours now.

Comment: Have you changed any of the system core files?

Comment: What is your php version number? Do you have a constructor in Tutorial Class? If yes, post the code.

Comment: Hey Sakibmoon, i haven't changed any of the system core files and the Tutorial Class appears exactly as posted in my above question with no constructor.

Comment: @che-azeh your're welcome. Glad I could help. If this solves your problem, you should accept the answer.